# how can I find exact solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the approach to solve $y'(t)=\alpha(y(t)-a+bt)^2$ analytically? $\alpha, a,b$ are positive constants.

I have tried MAPLE dsolve and got $y(t)=\sqrt(b/ \alpha) \tan \left[ \sqrt(\alpha b)(t-C) \right]+a-bp$.  I have checked the $y(t)$ by substitution that does confirm that it is the solution.

I wonder what method of solving or trick is used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Substituting $$v(t)=\frac{-2a\alpha+2bt\alpha}{2\alpha}+y(t)$$ then you will get
$$-b+v'(t)=\alpha v(t)^2$$ 
or
$$\frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{b+\alpha v(t)^2}=1$$
Can you finish?
It is a Riccati equation.

Answer (score 2):

After change $y(t)=z+a-bt$ we get separable equation
$$z'=\alpha z^2+b$$
If $\alpha b<0$ MAPLE gives complex solution.

Comment: Forgot to mention that all constants are positive.  My apologies. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=z-a+b t$ to make the equation
$$z'-\alpha  z^2-b=0$$ that is to say $$\frac 1 {t'}-\alpha  z^2-b=0\implies t'=\frac{1 }{ \alpha  z^2+b}$$ which looks to be quite simple.